# Problems with parsing dates using DateUtils

Tags: java, android, date, date-parsing, apache-commons-dateutils

I am trying to parse various slightly different date strings for an Android application.

Two examples are:

```
Thu, 20 Aug 2020 13:30:16 +0000
Wed, 19 Aug 2020 15:28:47 GMT
```

Here is how I tried parsing these Strings:

```
Date pubDate = org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.parseDate(dateString, 
    "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
```

As far as I can tell this should work, but I am getting `java.text.ParseException: Unable to parse the date: Wed, 19 Aug 2020 15:28:47 GMT` exceptions for both those examples. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your format is built into java.time

Use `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`; it works for both of your strings. It’s really the same format, only with the offset from UTC (or GMT) denoted differently. `DateTimeFormatter` is part of java.time, the modern Java date and time API. I recommend that you prefer java.time over `Date` and `DateUtils`, also because the `Date` class is poorly designed and long outdated.

```
    String s = "Thu, 20 Aug 2020 13:30:16 +0000";
    OffsetDateTime dt = OffsetDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME);
    System.out.println(dt);
```

Output is:

> 2020-08-20T13:30:16Z

Let’s try with your other string example:

```
    String s = "Wed, 19 Aug 2020 15:28:47 GMT";
```

> 2020-08-19T15:28:47Z

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your time zones are in 2 different formats:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

The first one looks like it follows the format:

```
EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z
```

While the second is of the format:

```
EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any problem with your formats.

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String[] dateStrings = { "Wed, 19 Aug 2020 15:28:47 GMT", "Thu, 20 Aug 2020 13:30:16 +0000" };
        for (String dateString : dateStrings) {
            Date pubDate = org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils.parseDate(dateString, "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",
                    "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");

            System.out.println(pubDate);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Wed Aug 19 16:28:47 BST 2020
Thu Aug 20 14:30:16 BST 2020
```

However, I strongly suggest you **stop** using the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat`. Switch to the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API and the corresponding formatting API (`java.time.format`). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

## Using modern date-time API:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test strings
        String[] dateStrings = { "Wed, 19 Aug 2020 15:28:47 GMT", "Thu, 20 Aug 2020 13:30:16 +0000" };

        // Define formatter
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
                .ofPattern("[EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z][EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz]", Locale.ENGLISH);

        for (String dateString : dateStrings) {
            ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);

            System.out.println(zdt);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-08-19T15:28:47Z[GMT]
2020-08-20T13:30:16Z
```

If your android version is not compliant with Java-8, you can backport using [ThreeTen-BackportCheck](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Check [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I gave the correct answer to Ole V.V's answer because he included the built-in date format `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`, but yours was just as correct.